# How to parse such string in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an address of a site:

`http://localhost/site/category/show/4:grafika`

How do I extract from that URL, the following strings?

- `'category/show/4'`
- `'grafika'`

Also from URLs like `http://localhost/site/category/show/4` I want to get  `'category/show/4'`

I've tried this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule /^(.+):(.+)$/ index.php?p=$1&l=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule /^(.+)$/ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But it's not working.

Comment: The `/` slash can neither appear before the `^` subject start or after the `$` subject end marker. It's also unclear if `site/category/show` is a real directory, or handled by a previous rule set.

Comment: site is a real directory and category/show isn't. Htaccess file is in site directory

Comment: I removed slashes, but now the website behaves like this: on localhost/site the 'p' parameter is: index.php which should be empty; on localhost/site/category/show/4 it shows website without javascript files

Comment: I've solved it. I had to copy three lines of RewriteCond before the last line.

Comment: Cleaned up the formatting of the bullet points so that it is easier to read. Code formatting also added to make that clear too.